# Jquery + CSS default BG color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with a css style of say green or blue, depending on the nth child color. I set it to orange using

```
<div id='yo' class='alternatingcolors' style='background-color: #FF9900;'>hello</div>
```

and I want to animate it back to its original color using jquery's

```
$('yo').animate({ backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 500);
```

However, neither transparent, inherit, null, or '' work.

How would I get it back to its original color? Essentially I want to animate it to the state before: style='background-color: #FF9900;' was set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup to 'yo' should be prefixed with a hash, e.g.:

```
$('#yo')
```

If that's not the issue:

You could store the original colour as data in the div, then restore it later:

```
<div id='yo' data-original-color='#FF9900' class='alternatingcolors'>
```

then:

```
$('#yo').animate({ backgroundColor: $('#yo').data('original-color') }, 500);
```

Comment: Woops, forgot the hash (typed it, not copy pasted). Is there any way to do it without storing it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, once you change a property (e.g. background-color) of an element, it is kept that way and there is no handy reference to the original.

Answer (score 0):

you can save its first background-color into a variable and then use it:

```
orange = $("yo").css("background-color")
```